# JQuery Grid Recursion for Minesweeper (click adjacent tiles)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, recursion, minesweeper

I have created a javascript version of minesweeper for a project, but I am trying to introduce an additional piece of functionality to better mimic the desktop version I remember playing.

My full code can be found at:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/um2H3/5/)

The particular function I am having difficulty with is the "clickTile()" function. The base requirement is to add the class 'selected' as well as the number of adjacent mines to the html for the clicked tile. The additional requirement I am trying to resolve is recursive autoclicking of tiles that do not have adjacent mines.

The function as it stands is:

```
function clickTile($tile) {
if ($tile.hasClass('mine')) {
    alert('game over');
    $('.mine').css("background", "red");
} else if (!$tile.hasClass("selected")){
    mines = getNumberOfAdjacentMines($tile);
    $tile.addClass("selected");
    $tile.html(mines);

    //recursively call clickTile function as long as there are no adjacent mines
    if (mines <= 0) {

        height = $('#field .row').length;
        width = $('#field .row .tile').length / height;
        rowNum = $tile.parent().prevAll('div').length
        colNum = $tile.prevAll('div').length

        $above = $tile    // td
        .parent()      // tr
        .parent()      // table or tbody
        .children('.row')
        .eq(rowNum - 1) // the row above this one
        .children('.tile')
        .eq(colNum)    // in the same column as this
        ;

        $below = $tile    // td
        .parent()      // tr
        .parent()      // table or tbody
        .children('.row')
        .eq(rowNum + 1) // the row below this one
        .children('.tile')
        .eq(colNum)    // in the same column as this
        ;

        if (rowNum > 0) {
            if (!$above.hasClass('mine') && !$above.hasClass('selected')){
                clickTile($above);
            }
        }

        if (colNum < (width-1)){
            if(!$tile.next().hasClass('selected')) {
                clickTile($tile.next());
            }
        }

        if (rowNum < (height-1)){
            if(!$below.hasClass('mine') && !$below.hasClass('selected')) {
                clickTile($below);
            }
        }

        if (colNum > 0){
            if (!$tile.prev().hasClass('selected')) {
                clickTile($tile.prev());
            }
        }

    }
}


}
```

To me, this SHOULD work to recursively click all tiles with 0 adjacent mines, but it does not. Can anyone help me understand where I may be going wrong with this? The behavior is very finicky.

Comment: It seems to work as expected, can you detail the problem?

Comment: Try a few more times, there are cases when it has too much recursion error, it has a mistake somewhere

Comment: Every 0 should have all the tiles above, below, left and right 'clicked', but oftentimes the 'below' tiles do not get clicked, and I am not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the variables are defined without the `var` keyword, so they are defined in the global scope.

In the clickTile function, you should replace

```
// rowNum is defined in the global scope, 
// Its value is overwritten with each recursive call
rowNum = $tile.parent().prevAll('div').length
```

with

```
// rowNum has the function as a scope, 
// its keeps different rowNum values for each recursive function call
var rowNum = $tile.parent().prevAll('div').length
```

The `rowNum` (and other variables) values are overwritten by recursive calls, so further conditions will behave incorrectly

```
if (rowNum > 0) { // rowNum can be anything at this point
    // The condition is randomly met
}
```

Add the `var` keyword to your variables, and your code should work as expected.

More about javascript scopes [here](http://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/).

Comment: This is great. Just what I needed. I haven't coded javascript in a while so I totally forgot about its scoping tendencies.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you had some trouble with selectors which were causing a too much recursion error, it was an endless loop sometimes. I tried to find the error and in some cases you sent to the recursive click function an empty selector, so it was no working properly. I did not like those selectors so made my own way of getting above, below, next and previous elements and it worked fine! Here is the code:

```
function clickTile($tile) {
var tiles=$(".tile");
var rows=8;
var columns=8;
var index=tiles.index($tile);    

if($tile.length ==0) return false;
if ($tile.hasClass('mine')) {
    alert('game over');
    $('.mine').css("background", "red");
} else if (!$tile.hasClass("selected")){
    mines = getNumberOfAdjacentMines($tile);

    $tile.html(mines);
    $tile.addClass("selected");

    //recursively call clickTile function as long as there are no adjacent mines
    if (mines <= 0) {

        if (index >= rows) {
            $above=$(tiles.get(index-rows));
            if (!$above.hasClass('mine') && !$above.hasClass('selected')){
                clickTile($above);
            }
        }

        if ((index+1)%columns !=0 ){
            $next=$(tiles.get(index+1))
            if(!$next.hasClass('selected')) {
                clickTile($next);
            }
        }

        if (index+rows < (rows*columns) ){
            $below=$(tiles.get(index+rows));
            if(!$below.hasClass('mine') && !$below.hasClass('selected')) {
                clickTile($below);
            }
        }

        if ((index+1)%columns != 1){
            $prev=$(tiles.get(index-1))
            if (!$prev.hasClass('selected')) {
                clickTile($prev);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

And here is a shorter version for travelling neighbours:

```
        if (mines <= 0) {

            var posInRow=(index+1)%columns;
            var neighbours=[];
            if(index >= rows) neighbours.push(index-rows);//up
            if(index+rows < (rows*columns) ) neighbours.push(index+rows);//down
            if(posInRow != 0) neighbours.push(index+1);//right
            if(posInRow != 1) neighbours.push(index-1);//left
            for(var i=0;i<neighbours.length;i++){
                var neighbour=$(tiles.get(neighbours[i]));
                if (!neighbour.hasClass('mine') && !neighbour.hasClass('selected')){
                    clickTile(neighbour);
                }
            }

        }
```